# Slicing the 2-sphere one circle at a time

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose I take the standard 2-sphere embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, translated so that the south pole is sitting at the origin. Then, I take any great circle, make a cut at the north pole, and lay the torn circle ‘flat’ across the $x_1,x_2$-plane. Suppose I do this for all great circles in the 2-sphere. What have I obtained? Would this be the stereographic projection?

Any comments would be appreciated… even if the answer to my question isn’t known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you obtain is the [azimuthal equidistant projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection).

It is not the same as stereographic projection. Sterographic projection would be if you took any great circle, make a cut at the north pole $N$, and then for each point $P$ on the torn circle you extend the ray $\vec{NP}$ until it passes through a point on the $x_1,x_2$ plane; that latter point is what you project $P$ to.

One difference between these two projections is that the radius of the azimuthal equidistant projection is equal to the half-circumference of a great circle, whereas the stereographic projection covers the whole plane. In more detail, if you consider any great semicircle connecting the north pole $N$ to the south pole $S$ (which is the point where the sphere touches the plane), that great semicircle has finite length but its stereographic image in the $x_1,x_2$ plane is an infinite ray based at the point $S$.